# When I click on a label, the menu button disappears

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

In the following code when I click the on the label the menu button disappears from the screen. How can I solve this?

I try this on windows 10, using kivy 1.9.2dev.

The code just creates a screenmanager, and then adds two screens. Then adds a vertical and a horizontal box layouts.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
<TheScreenManager>:
    Screen1:

<Screen1>:
    name: 'screen1'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        BoxLayout: # Menu
            size_hint_y: None
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            height: 48

            DropDown1:


        Label: 
            id: label
            text: 'I am a label'
            font_size: 30
            size_hint_y: 0.99


<DropDown1>:
    Button:
        id:btn1
        text: 'btn1'
        on_release: dropdown1.open(self)
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '48dp'

    DropDown:
        id: dropdown1
        on_parent: self.dismiss()
        on_select: btn1.text = '{}'.format(args[1])

        Button:
            text: 'My first Item'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 44
            on_release: dropdown1.select('item1')


''')


class Screen1(Screen):
    pass


class DropDown1(DropDown):
    pass

class DropDown2(DropDown):
    pass


class EraserDropDown(DropDown):
    pass


class Screen2(Screen):
    pass


class TheScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class TheApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return TheScreenManager()


TheApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is, that you are inheriting DropDown in your classes. And you are creating another DropDown in that class in kvlang.
Try inheriting BoxLayout instead. This should fix your issue.
Like this:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

Builder.load_string('''
<TheScreenManager>:
    Screen1:

<Screen1>:
    name: 'screen1'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        BoxLayout: # Menu
            size_hint_y: None
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            height: 48

            DropDown1:


        Label: 
            id: label
            text: 'I am a label'
            font_size: 30
            size_hint_y: 0.99


<DropDown1>:
    Button:
        id:btn1
        text: 'btn1'
        on_release: dropdown1.open(self)
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '48dp'

    DropDown:
        id: dropdown1
        on_parent: self.dismiss()
        on_select: btn1.text = '{}'.format(args[1])

        Button:
            text: 'My first Item'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 44
            on_release: dropdown1.select('item1')


''')


class Screen1(Screen):
    pass


class DropDown1(BoxLayout):
    pass

class Screen2(Screen):
    pass


class TheScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class TheApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return TheScreenManager()


TheApp().run()
```